# Nodejs res.redirect not working?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, redirect

I have my Angularjs website and I am trying to route all my `Http` traffic to `Https` and for that, I have written below code but it is not working, every time I am opening my website on `Http` redirect is not happening.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public')); // Website part added
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))

app.use(function(req,res,next) {

    if(req.headers["x-forwarded-proto"] == "http") {

        res.redirect("https://" + req.headers.host + req.url);
        return next();
    } else {
        console.log('Request was not HTTP');
        return next();
    } 
});

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
});
```

Can anyone please tell me why this is not working ??

**Edit** - I noticed that whenever I am opening my website then `most of the times` this middleware is `not getting called`. How can this be possible ??

**Edit** - I have my set `base href="/"` in my `index.html` will it cause any problem.

Comment: Remove `return next();`.

Comment: Can you please explain why "because of `return next()` it is not working" ??

Comment: @AikonMogwai No it's still not working.

Comment: does it enters in this condition : `(req.headers["x-forwarded-proto"] == "http")` ?

Comment: @user1851595 only a single time I noticed, but even at that time, it was never redirected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello actually the mistake I was doing was I was putting `redirecting` on the middleware after the setting the `/public` directory, but the right way was to put it before setting `/public` directory.

**Right Code**

```
app.use(function(req,res,next) {

    if(req.headers["x-forwarded-proto"] == "http") {

        res.redirect("https://" + req.headers.host + req.url);
        return next();
    } else {
        console.log('Request was not HTTP');
        return next();
    }
});
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public')); // Website part added
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
```

Because of which Https was not enforcing but now everything is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you can't rely on `x-forwarded-proto` header in all case.

`x-forwarded-proto` is generally set when you run your app behind a proxy, and apparently it's not your case.

It would be better to use `req.protocol` instead:

```
if (req.protocol === "http") {
  res.redirect("https://" + req.headers.host + req.url);
} else {
  console.log('Request was not HTTP');
  return next();
}
```

Or  you can use the handy *Express* request property [req.secure](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.secure).

Comment: req.secure is coming false for all requests.

Comment: Still not working. Also, whenever I am opening my website I don't know why but this middleware is not getting called.

Comment: Even for `HTTPS` request req.protocol is printing `HTTP` request.

Comment: Yes `req.secure` is `false` on http.

Comment: Not only for http but it is coming false for HTTPS also.

Comment: Have you really tried to follow the link to the documentation that I kindly provided in my answer ?

Comment: I just wrote the code you mentioned in your answer and also i tried to print the value of req.secure nothing worked.

Comment: There is probably a problem with the setting of your https server. Sorry for not helping you much.

Comment: Hey I have found the solution, anyways thanks for helping me :)